# Jetpack Mobile Theme: when on smartphone on categories the theme suddenly changes to jetpack mobile theme even though it's deactivated

Tags: categories, themes, mobile, plugin-jetpack

I'm having a little problem with my mobile theme. I'm using a Momentous Lite child theme for my website. On my Smartphone the home page looks as it's supposed to do but as soon as I switch to a category, the theme changes into jetpack's mobile theme even though I deactivated that... Does anyone know why?

My website: http://www.inflamedpassion.com
example of a category: http://tansania.inflamedpassion.com

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you most likely need to clear your cache. If you have any plugins like WP Super Cache or WP Fastest Cache installed then navigate to there settings and click clear all cache. Also if you have CloudFlare (or something similar) running on your website then you can purge the cache on that.

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help!